# \printbibliography -- One Entry per Page

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I would like to generate my bibliography with a *single entry per page*.

What changes do I need to make to the MWE below to effectively generate the bibliograpy as it appears with the following manully generated code:

```
\begin{preview}
  \fullcite{goossens93}
\end{preview}
\begin{preview}
  \fullcite{greenwade93}
\end{preview}
\begin{preview}
  \fullcite{knuth79}
\end{preview}
```

The following needs to be in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2pt}%
```

which yields the desired 3 page document:

[image]

I just realized that the citation label is missing in the image -- I *do* want that displayed.

#### Bonus Question:

I would like to have a custom macro invoked at the end of each bibliography entry -- passing the parameter of the citation key. One of the planed uses of this is to add a link to the .bibtex to make easy corrections.

I can post a separate question if needed, but suspect that solving the orginal question may also provide this capability.

#### MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{complete-bibliography.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author   ={Michel Goossens},
    title    ={The {LaTeX} Companion},
    year     ={1993},
    publisher={Addison-Wesley},
    address  ={Reading, Massachusetts},
}

@article{greenwade93, 
    author ={George D. Greenwade},
    title  ={The {C}omprehensive {TeX} {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})},
    year   ={1993},
    journal={TUGBoat},
    volume ={14},
    number ={3},
    pages  ={342--351},
    url    ={www.ctan.org},
}

@book{knuth79,
    author   ={Donald E. Knuth},
    title    ={{TeX} and Metafont, New Directions in Typesetting},
    year     ={1979},
    publisher={American Mathematical Society and Digital Press},
    address  ={Stanford},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{complete-bibliography.bib}

%\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
%\setlength\PreviewBorder{2pt}%


\begin{document} 
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography% <-- Make this equivalent to below.
%% -------------- Desired Output
%\begin{preview}
%\fullcite{goossens93}
%\end{preview}
%\begin{preview}
%\fullcite{greenwade93}
%\end{preview}
%\begin{preview}
%\fullcite{knuth79}
%\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an option that redefines the `biblatex` bibliography environment to use the `preview environment` rather than a list and modifies the `finentry` bibmacro to close the `preview` environment and add in your bonus macro with the entry key. There's probably a more elegant way.

### Update to show use of `tcolorbox` (requested in comments)

The trick is that the end of the `tcolorbox` has to come after the current group in the `finentry` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{goossens93,
  author   ={Michel Goossens},
  title    ={The {LaTeX} Companion},
  year     ={1993},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley},
  address  ={Reading, Massachusetts},
}
@article{greenwade93, 
  author ={George D. Greenwade},
  title  ={The {C}omprehensive {TeX} {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})},
  year   ={1993},
  journal={TUGBoat},
  volume ={14},
  number ={3},
  pages  ={342--351},
  url    ={www.ctan.org},
}
@book{knuth79,
  author   ={Donald E. Knuth},
  title    ={{TeX} and Metafont, New Directions in Typesetting},
  year     ={1979},
  publisher={American Mathematical Society and Digital Press},
  address  ={Stanford},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{colback=green!10, colframe=blue}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2pt}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\newcommand{\startbibentry}{%
  \begin{preview}%
    \begin{tcolorbox}}
\newcommand{\stopbibentry}{%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
  \end{preview}}
\newcommand{\showentrykey}[1]{The entry key is: \texttt{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \finentry
  \par
  \smallskip
  \leftskip\labelnumberwidth
  \showentrykey{\strfield{entrykey}}%
  \par
  \aftergroup\stopbibentry}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}~}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {}
  {}
  {\startbibentry
   \hangindent\labelnumberwidth
   \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
     \printfield{labelprefix}%
     \printfield{labelnumber}}}
\begin{document} 
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: This works great. Do you know how I can _also_ wrap each entry within a `\begin{tcolorbox}...\end{tcolorbox}`. Let me know if this warrants a new question.

Comment: @PeterGrill, might be worth a new question. The obvious option (which presumably you tried) doesn't work. You might get a quicker answer with more eyes looking at it.

Comment: @PeterGrill ooo! I did it! I'll modify my answer.